# Arithmetic syntax error with a number variable

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I am having a difficulty with an arithmetic syntax error.

I am reading the name of text files from the command line and count the number of the lines of each file.

```
NUM=$(wc -l "$text")
```

and then I want to check whether NUM is odd or not.

So I put,

```
REMAINDER=$(( $NUM % 2 ))
if [ $REMAINDER -ne 0 ] ; then 
    echo "Odd number"
fi
```

However, it seems like there is a problem with

```
REMAINDER=$(( $NUM % 2 ))
```

$NUM doesn't seem to be regarded as a number but a '.txt' file. When I checked NUM by itself and it worked fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print `$NUM`, after

```
NUM=$(wc -l "$text")
```

you probably will see (on Linux) a number and a filename on the same line, with some whitespace.

For example:

```
1842 basic.c
```

That string isn't a number, and you usually would read just the first token with your choice of shell/sed/awk, etc., to use *that* as a number.

@steeldriver suggests this for getting just the number:

```
NUM=$(wc -l < "$text")
```

which works (tested with Debian).

Comment: ... or use `wc -l < "$text"` (wc should return only the count when reading input via stdin instead of from a named file)

Comment: There are several variations (and aside from Linux, several systems that could be considered).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Yes it prints both the number and the name of the file when I do that. I'll try to take the number only as you suggest! I'll be able to choose your answer in 5 minutes!